# Folder and file permission issues on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, apache

I've written a PHP script that takes the results of a MySQL query, json_encodes the results and finally does a file_put_contents() action.  When running my Bitnami WAMP dev-server on my PC, the script executes perfectly.  However, when clone my git project on my Mac (running Yosemite).  I get permission denied upon trying to executing the file_put_contents() function.  Here is my script:

```
<?php
// All Articles to JSON //
if( array_key_exists("makejson", $_REQUEST) ) {

// Class to Serialize The JSON
class ArrayValue implements JsonSerializable {
public function __construct(array $array) {
    $this->array = $array;
 }

 public function jsonSerialize() {
     return $this->array;
 }
}

// Designate the file
$file = "articles.json";

// FHA articles query
$milArticles = $dataConnection->SelectColsWhere( "text_news", "active='1' ORDER BY ndate DESC", "textnewsid,ndate,ntitle,sentence" );

if(count($milArticles) > 0){

  $json_data = json_encode( new ArrayValue($milArticles), JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );

  // Check for JSON errors
  if ($json_data === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {

   throw new \LogicException(sprintf("Failed to parse json string '%s', error: '%s'", $json_data , json_last_error_msg()));

    } else {

      file_put_contents($file, $json_data, LOCK_EX);


   }
 }
}// END OF MAKE JSON
```

This is the error I get:

```
[Mon Feb 09 16:06:20.522798 2015] [:error] [pid 686] [client 127.0.0.1:50195] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(articles.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/myuser/Sites/PIXEL/militaryinfo/restrict/includes/articleJson.php on line 33, referer: http://militaryinfo/restrict/submit_JSON.php
```

Here are the permissions in the directory I'm trying to write to:

```
drwxr-xr-x  15 myuser  staff   510 Feb  6 19:13 restrict
```

The solutions I've heard are running an unmask() in PHP and a chmod() but I haven't had luck with either.  Even running chmod or chown in the Terminal doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

Run `echo exec('whoami');` in a `PHP` script and run the PHP script from browser. It gives you who is the owner of the server application.

Then `chown` that user and group both and provide appropriate permissions as you wish. Something like:

```
chown -R user:user /my/folder
```

`user` is discovered from the PHP script.

Comment: It looks like with Apache installed with Mac OS X, that the owner of all files/folders is _www.  So I'd just need to change the user to 'myuser'.  Like:  chown -R myuser:user /my/folder ?

Comment: `chown -R _www:_www /my/folder`. Then, you can do a `chmod -R 755 /my/folder`. Use `sudo` if required.

Comment: I got this error now:  [Mon Feb 09 17:02:51.339966 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1095] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

Comment: The end result was it found that the file I named in my variable 'articles.json' existed, it unlinked that file abd failed to create a new articles.json file.